# Change search query of a custom post type on the admin panel in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I want to change the query of search a custom post type in wordpress admin panel. I use this method:

```
function change_admin_search( $query ) {

    $post_type = 'custom_post_type';

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
        return;

    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $num = range(0, 9);
    $persianNumbersOnly = str_replace( $num,$persian, $search_term);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace( $persian, $num, $search_term);
    $query->query_vars['s'] = $englishNumbersOnly;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_admin_search' );
```

In this query, it search only with `$englishNumbersOnly`. I want to search with `$englishNumbersOnly` OR `$persianNumbersOnly`, and `$query->query_vars['s']` have a `OR` in query. Actually have a query like this :

> `post Like "%$englishNumbersOnly%" OR post Like "%$persianNumbersOnly%"`

Thanks

Comment: Why these two variables `$englishNumbersOnly` and `$persianNumbersOnly` are the same? What are you trying to do with `str_replace`? Can you explain what the end result was? When you ran your snippet, did you get any error(s)/warning(s)?

Comment: @Ruvee Excuse me, that is my mistake. these two variables are not equal. I update the question. Thanks

Comment: @Ruvee In post list, some posts have English numbers in title and some posts have persian numbers. when user search by english numbers, only first group comes in result, and when user search by persian numbers, only second group shows in result. I want to show all result ( persian and english )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [WP_Query::parse_search](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_search/) method. As @Ruvee says, we can use `'+'` sign to feed more than one search term for `'s'` argument, But In parse_search method, the `$searchand` value is `' AND '` and it ands search_terms. I Customize parse_search for `custom_post_type` to use `OR` instead of `AND`

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to show all result ( persian and english )"*

Search term argument of wp_query (i.e 's') accepts more than one keyword/term. The way you could feed it more than one keyword is to use `+` sign in the middle of the keywords, and it should be a string not an array. Like this:

- `$query->set( 's' => 'keywordOne+keywordTwo+keywordThree' )`

We could use this to modify your query:

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_admin_search');

function change_admin_search($query)
{

    $post_type = 'custom_post_type';

    if (is_admin() && in_array($query->get('post_type'), array($post_type))) {
        $search_term = sanitize_text_field($query->query_vars['s']);
        $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
        $num = range(0, 9);
        $persianNumbersOnly = str_replace($num, $persian, $search_term);
        $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($persian, $num, $search_term);

        $query->set('s',  strval($englishNumbersOnly) . '+' . strval($persianNumbersOnly));
    }
    
}
```

**Note:**

- I've combined and modified your `if` statements.
- I've changed your "post type" conditional check so that you could use more than one post type.
- I've used `sanitize_text_field` function on the searched keyword.
- I've used `set` method for setting the `s` value.
- Using `strval` function is not necessary, but I've used it to make sure you don't get any error(s)/warning(s).

---

This has not been tested but, theoretically, it should work. Let me know if you could get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it does not work. The '+' sign doesn't work and it does not return any result

Comment: The '+' sign does not work because it search for Existence of both of keywords/terms. I solve the problem. Thank You for your help